# How to transfer Sqlite database from Free to Paid version of app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created an iPhone application in a lite version and a paid version using different targets. In my application I used a SQLite database.  If the user wishes to update the lite version to paid then how can I import or transfer SQLite database from lite to paid version?

Comment: there is a paid version of SQLite?

Comment: @Grady Yes, i used sqlite database both version for store image url.

Comment: just looked, and SQLite is in the public domain, are you thinking of MySQL?

Comment: Sorry Grady, i didn't getting your concept, I am create IPhone application using sqlite database So I want to upgrate free version to paid version that time old db(lite db) import in paid version.

Comment: @GradyPlayer he means lite and paid version of his app, not SQLite...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the URL handler approach: [described here](http://mobileorchard.com/lite-to-paid-iphone-application-data-migrations-with-custom-url-handlers/). Or you could allow the user to save (export) their data to iCloud and then read it back in (import).

Comment: If the data is big then iCloud is the option to go for.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd recommend that you create a single application and allow InApp Purchase to upgrade from lite to paid version.
2. Since you can't go back in time, in your case the "lite" version will need to send the information to your backend server, and that server should update the "paid" version with the data.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, In my application is not back end server. I just create sqlite db in app and store dynamically some images and other parameter so I want to transfer these db data from lite to paid version

Comment: Then I'd go for the approach that @Wain suggested in his answer.

Comment: Can i use different application name for free and paid version if i use inApp purchase

Comment: please can u explain second point little bit more?

Comment: @patilAmol If you have a server, then you can send the necessary data from the lite version to that server and keep it in a database. Once the data is saved you can fetch that data in the paid version.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can dump old data into new data .
2. From server download upgrade sql